# Jupyter notebook autocomplete not working while using in new cell

Tags: python, autocomplete, jupyter-notebook

In jupyter notebook, while I import numpy(import numpy as np) and use (np. TAB) in the same cell autocomplete works and I get methods. However, when I import numpy and try to use np. Tab in another cell autocomplete is not working. Could you guys help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you clarify what versions of Python and Jupyter you're using?